# Посимвольный вывод строки в консоль, без очистки экрана и с визуализацией перебора

Tags: powershell

Необходимо вывести строку-образец в командную строку консоли, но без очистки экрана и с визуализацией перебора символов. В наличии вариант с двумя циклами, но хотелось бы получить вариант с одним циклом. Решение (не моё) существует, но интересно было бы взглянуть на другие возможные способы.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения с двумя циклами:

```
if ($args[0]){$arr = $args[0]}else{$arr='Привет мир!'}
$num = 32..126+1040..1103
for($i=0;$i -lt $arr.length;$i++){
    do {
        $m = [char]($num|get-random)
        write-host "`b$m" -nonew
        sleep -m 10
    } while($arr[$i] -cne $m)
    write-host $(if($arr[-1] -eq $m){"`b$m`n"}else{$m}) -nonew
}
```

Вариант с одним циклом:

```
for ($s, $i, $m = "Hello, world!", 0, -join[Char[]](32..126+1040..1103);;) { # цикл бесконечен
  switch (($c = $m[(Get-Random -Min 0 -Max $m.Length)]) -ceq $s[$i]) {
    $true  { $r += $c; $i++}
    $false { [Console]::Write("`r$r$c`b")}
  }
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
  if ($i -eq $s.Length) { [Console]::Write("`r$r "); break } # условие выхода из цикла
}
```